# psycopg installation problem

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I've recently installed django and psycop2. However python is refusing to use it below is the error. Can someone please help?

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
```

Comment: This looks like OSX, right? How did you install it? Macports? Homebrew?

Comment: I compiled installed it myself initially then using macports....Anyway i can remove it all?

Comment: I think it's an issue with architecture. The python is compile for 64 bit and the module for 32 bit. Or vice versa, I'm not sure. You can remove it by just deleting it out of the site-packages directory.

Answer (score 1):

macports is terrible for python/django development, everything seems to be out of data.

I have my team doing the following for postgres:

1. Download and install [postgresql 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx) but read the README before
   installing !!!
2. Download psycopg2 source from http://initd.org/pub/software/psycopg/
3. Edit the setup.cfg to set pg_config to
   /Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin/pg_config

Then install with

```
python setup.py install
```

I'd recommend using virtualenv as well,  you want to stay away from the base Mac OS X python install as much as possible.